# Is it possible to define method argument with default values in Java?

Tags: java, methods

Really want to initialise some arguments in a Java method eg

`public void delete(String name, int user_id=0)
{
//method body
}`

so that the `user_id` does not have to necessarily be passed.
But i'm getting this Eclipse error that the token is invalid. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java != PHP.

But you can write:

```
public void delete(String name){
  delete(name, 0);
}

public void delete(String name, int user_id){/* ...*/}
```

Comment: oops! i think my brain is still not healed from the PHP infections. I wanted to avoid having many methods..but its ok

Comment: There is no way in java to have a default parameter. The only way is to have multiple methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can uses generic bounded methods. I kind of think they are messy and only recommend it if you actually have a deed to do it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

I've found youtube videos on how to do this and it does work. But like I said, personally if it is only 2 or 3 methods you are making I would make the methods, cause this is messy.